# Calling a modal popup with TargetControl in another UpdatePanel in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'm trying to call a Modal Popup, but the TargetControl is in a different UpdatePanel than where the ModalPopupExtender resides.

Here's the code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        Test
        </asp:Panel>
        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="Panel1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
            DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="LinkButton1" PopupControlID="Panel1">
        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I run the page the error "An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends." is shown.

I'm trying to put a Triggers statement in the UpdatePanel2 but nothing changes:

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
```

Is possible to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the extender to the first update panel:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="Panel1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
            DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="LinkButton1" PopupControlID="Panel1">
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        Test
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```